# p:galleria does not display small image and description

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I used primafeces galleria in my website.It is connected to mysql and I can display images from database.But small images and description don't display.What is the my problem.How should I display them?

```
    <p:galleria value="#{gallery.Print()}" var="news"
        panelWidth="650" panelHeight="400" showCaption="true">
        <h:outputLink
            value="http://localhost:8080/newsSite/faces/template/index.xhtml">
            <p:graphicImage value="#{news.image}" alt="#{news.title}" title="#{news.title}"
                width="100%" height="100%" />
        </h:outputLink>
    </p:galleria>
```

Bean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="gallery")
@SessionScoped
public class Bean {
       private Statement st;
        private ResultSet rs;

        public List<galleryNews> Print(){

            Connect nesne = new Connect();
            List<galleryNews> galleryList = new ArrayList<galleryNews>();

            try {
                st=nesne.getCon().createStatement();
                rs=st.executeQuery("select * from galleryNews");

                while(rs.next()){
                    galleryNews obj = new galleryNews();
                obj.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                obj.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
                obj.setText(rs.getString("text"));
                obj.setImage(rs.getString("image"));
                galleryList.add(obj);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
            return galleryList;
        }
```

Comment: In what folder are your images located? Instead of `value` in `<p:graphicImage>` try to use `name`.

Comment: My image's links are in image column of galleryNews table in database

Comment: What do you see in the browser when you look at the source of the page, network infoetc?

Comment: You state that 'small' images are not shown. Bigger images are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by your `p:graphicImage` being nested in `h:outputLink` - `p:galleria` needs `p:graphicImage` to be its direct child, otherwise it seems unable to pull the `alt` and `title` values.

I was able to fix this by moving the link into the `p:graphicImage` and providing some additional styles - note I used `p:link` with no label instead of `h:outputLink`:

```
<p:galleria value="#{gallery.Print()}" var="news" panelWidth="650" panelHeight="400"
    showCaption="true">

    <p:graphicImage value="#{news.image}" alt="#{news.title}" title="#{news.title}"
        width="100%" height="100%">

        <p:link value=""
            style="width:100%; height:100%; display:block; position:absolute;"
            href="http://localhost:8080/newsSite/faces/template/index.xhtml" />

    </p:graphicImage>
</p:galleria>
```

I tested this in Firefox, Chrome and IE 11, seems working to me, though I'm not really sure if this is the best solution to your problem.

Comment: According to the question, bigger images ARE shown (unless the post is misleading). So in that case this answer is not valid. And looking at the [source of the galleria](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/galleria/GalleriaRenderer.java) there is nothing that indicates only graphicImage s can be rendered... Did you check with other content?

Comment: Well, in my environment the `alt` and `title` of `p:graphicImage` were displayed as "undefined" when the image was nested in link - nesting it in reversed order did the trick for me, so I was hoping it would help OP at least with the missing description.

Comment: I got an error "<p:link> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: link"

Comment: That is rather weird. What PF version are you using? And do you have `<h:head></h:head>` on your form?

Comment: Thank you so much.I upgrated primefaces version.It correct  right

Comment: @mery glad it helped. I still need to learn not to assume anything about versions people use :-)